# How to set ColumnBar series to a chart

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, range

I want to project a column with a given width (e.i. from 16-05-03 12:00:00 to 16-07-26 12:00:00) and that it projects all along x axis (e.i labels bool, int, long, bool, int long) (see picture below).

[image]

For that I have 2 chart areas both having the same parameters.

```
private void AddChartAreas(string name)
{
        // AxisX
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(name);
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisX.Interval = 1;

        // AxisY
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.Interval = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
        minDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000);
        maxDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000); // or DateTime.Now;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;

        chart1.ChartAreas[name].Axes[0].Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].Axes[1].Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

        chart1.ChartAreas[name].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].Position.Height = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].Position.Width = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 90;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 80;
        chart1.ChartAreas[name].InnerPlotPosition.X = 10;
}
```

The first chart area (**bar series**) is created as following:

```
var series = new Series { 
             Name = "S1", 
             Color = Color.LightSlateGray, 
             ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar
};

chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

The second chart area (**range column series**):

```
var series = new Series { 
                 Name = "S2", 
                 Color = Color.LightSlateGray, 
                 ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn
};

chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

To add points for the **bar series** simply bind 2 lists for x, y:

```
        var lables = new string[6];
        var values = new DateTime[6];

        minDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000); 

        // Dummy data
        lables[0] = "bool";
        lables[1] = "int";
        lables[2] = "long";
        lables[3] = "bool";
        lables[4] = "int";
        lables[5] = "long";

        // Dummy data
        values[0] = minDate.AddMonths(10);
        values[1] = minDate.AddMonths(10);
        values[2] = minDate.AddMonths(10);
        values[3] = minDate.AddMonths(10);
        values[4] = minDate.AddMonths(10);
        values[5] = minDate.AddMonths(10);

        // Simply bind 2 lists
        series[0].Points.DataBindXY(lables, values);
```

For the **column range series**:

```
pointIndex = series[1].Points.AddXY(values2[1], values2[5]);
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

How to make it such that it looks like first picture.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.

Instead of a **range column** I make a **range bar** series and set `PointWidth` to `5`:

```
var series = new Series { 
                 Name = "S2", 
                 Color = Color.LightSlateGray, 
                 ChartType = SeriesChartType.Rangebar
};

series["PointWidth"] = "5";

chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

Than when plotting:

```
minDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000); 

values2[0] = minDate.AddMonths(1);    
values2[1] = minDate.AddMonths(2);

pointIndex = series2.Points.AddXY(values2[1], values2[1]);
```

That will give me the results I want.